# Xcode - Unable to retrieve authentication token from server

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, xcode8

When running the build step to upload the symbol files from Xcode I get the
following errors:

```
/Pods/FirebaseCrash/**upload-sym-util.bash:322:** Unable to retrieve
authentication token from server.
```

I got the error after the update **(Xcode 8.0)**. I removed all Firebase's Pods and the file (upload-sym-util.bash) doesn't exist (**i removed it**) but I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered the exact same issue and found out that it is resulting from a weird date & time incompatibility. When I set the computer's date & time to the current date & time in Turkey, the issue has been resolved. As far as I tested, the error is emerging when the time incompatibility is more than an hour.